# How to extract information from last 2 lines of a text file in DOS

Tags: batch-file, dos

I would like to get the time stamp from the last two lines in a file that looks something like this using DOS:

```
2/3/2013 18:30:00   This is line 1
2/3/2013 19:24:05   This is line 2
2/3/2013 20:10:40   This is line 3
2/3/2013 21:06:00   This is line 4
2/3/2013 22:50:31   This is line 5
```

Currently, my script looks like this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0

for /f "tokens=2" %%x in (inputfile.txt) do (
    set /a i=!i!+1
    set time!i!=%%x
)

set /a lasttime=time!i!
set /a j=!i!-1
set /a prevtime=time!j!
echo %lasttime%
echo %prevtime%
endlocal
```

The output only have the hours portion, no minutes and seconds:

```
21
22
```

Please tell me how to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your using the `SET /A` command for assigning `lasttime` and `prevtime`.

`SET /A` is used for arithmetic operations, and everything you are feeding it must be converted to a number, even though you are not doing anything with the value apart from storing it to another variable. Your `time!i!` reference evaluates to `22:50:31` but in the context of the `SET /A` command it is immediately converted to the closest numeric value, which is `22`. Same happens with `time!j!`.

To fix the issue, just use a simple `SET` command and mixed expansion, like this:

```
...
set lasttime=!time%i%!
set /a j=!i!-1
set prevtime=!time%j%!
...
```

Also, if all you need is the last two lines, you could consider an alternative approach. Instead of using a separate variable for every line of the text, you could use just two: one to store the current line, the other to store the previous value of the former. Here's what I mean:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=2" %%x in (inputfile.txt) do (
    set prevtime=!lasttime!
    set lasttime=%%x
)

echo %lasttime%
echo %prevtime%
endlocal
```

Comment: Your solution is much better. Thanks, Andriy.